# Snap Input Rules

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, snapping

I need to snap polyline features in one layer to the nearest polyline in another layer. However, I want only the ENDS of the INPUT to snap to the nearest VERTEX in the environment layer. Is there a way I can set a rule like this? As it stands now, any vertex in the input within the tolerance will snap to a nearby vertex in the environment layer, creating extra line segments I don't want instead of the simplest possible path (the ultimate desired output).

If it adds any helpful context (and actually a followup question I may ask separately in another post), my input line segment should actually "share" or be connected by the portion of the line that it's snapping to. In other words, I have disjointed line segments where the best route to connect them is part of another polyline feature.[image: Orange polylines need to be connected by blue segment between the two]

So, in this example, the orange lines should be connected by the blue segment in the midde. I add this second part of the whole picture of what I'm doing in case there's a better way to do this altogether; my initial thought was to snap the ends of the orange lines to the nearest vertex on the blue, and then find a way to 
"cut out" that little connecter blue segment and somehow add it to my orange line to make a complete line.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea:

1. Create a new layer from your input extracting only the endpoints of your lines. You can do it with BOTH_ENDS setting in [Feature Vertices To Points (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003p000000)
2. Snap to this layer, not to initial input.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, it looks like you could use the [snap(editing) tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000) and set the 'snap environment' parameters as you described.[image]

Comment: No, that is the problem. I see that you can set the environment settings, but I am not sure if/how you can set rules for the INPUT.